# Defining schema for nested JSON structures in AWS Athena

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have nested json with below format:

```
{
   "id": "212",
   "profile": "unknown",
   "role": 
        "{
            "admin_role": "yes",
            "developer_role":"yes" 
         }"
}
```

My goal is to define schema while creating table but facing error for role since the data is provided as string.

Expectation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE profile
id bigint,
profile string,
role struct<
    admin_role:string,
    developer_role:string
    >
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
location 's3://<bucket_name>/<path>';
```

Any suggestion to define schema for role at first level table creation itself?

Thanks

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, which might be a bigger problem for you.

Comment: @jordanm  can i know the reason

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with your JSON and after correcting it as shown below was able to query it. Makes sure you have each JSON record on separate line.

```
{"id":"212","profile":"unknown","role":{"admin_role":"yes","developer_role":"yes"}}
```

DDL used to query JSON:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sf_73855155`(
  `id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `profile` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `role` struct<admin_role:string,developer_role:string> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'paths'='id,profile,role') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '<path>'
```

Output:

[image]